# Why does the Java JDK not set its own path after installation on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, system-variable

#### Problem:

After installing Java SE version 14.0.1 I tried to run the command `java` in CMD because I wanted to check if everything works as it should, but an error occurred because CMD could not find what I wanted.

I checked the system environment variable to see if the path for the Java JDK was set, but no, it was not set.

#### Question:

**Why was the path not set by the Java JDK after installing Java SE 14.0.1?**

Comment: Oh no, now you have to set it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depens on the installator provider by the combianation of vendor and version. As far as I know the AdoptOpenJDK add the PATH variable